# Keyword not supported

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, windows, connection

I saw whole bunch of answers but I still can't fine one for me.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="conString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=wb_lab_1;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.MysqlClient"
    />
</connectionStrings>
```

I can't make connection string on windows using windows authentication. I've also tried:

`Server=127.0.0.1;Database=wb_lab_1;IntegratedSecurity=yes;Uid=auth_windows;`

`Server=(local);Database=wb_lab_1;IntegratedSecurity=yes;Uid=auth_windows;`

But I'm still having `Keyword not supported` error. Where am I wrong?

---

UPD: here is how I'm trying to connect in C#:

```
String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ToString();
conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString); // here I got an Exception
```

Comment: replace providerName with ` providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: @Smart, still nothing. I've also tried `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`.

Comment: are you sure `Date source ` is correct ?

Comment: @Smart, yes, I can connect with it in MS SQL Server and also it generates when I open database in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ToString();
conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString); // here I got an Exception
```

To:

```
String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString); // should work
```

Comment: Wow, when I changed all to `System.Data.SqlClient` it starts to work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have mentioned that in the first comment to Change it to `System.Data.SqlClient`!!

Comment: Yeah looks like you were trying to connect to an MS SQL Server database using a MySQL connection string. Please it helped.

Comment: @Smart Yes you did. I think it needed changing in two locations. So a combination of both answers seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
providerName="System.Data.MysqlClient"
```

to

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but still nothing.

Comment: what type of database are you using ?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: The key was to change everywhere `Mysql.Data.MysqlClient` to `System.Data.SqlClient`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have mentioned that in first comment, but unfortunately you did not choose it as your answer

Comment: you suppose to choose my answer as your question answer

Comment: Post you comment as answer and I will accept it. But the key was to use everywhere in code `System.Data.SqlClient` instead of `Mysql.Data.MysqlClient`. Because your current answer does't represent my issue.

Comment: post my comment as answer